# Should I block off the soffit vents in the vicinity of my bathroom exhaust vent which is in the soffit?

Tags: bathroom, vent, soffit

I've seen the other threads on here warning against venting a bathroom fan to a soffit:  People warn against the moist air heading right back up the surrounding soffit vents and into the attic (especially in a colder climate like mine--Wisconsin).  My plan to counteract this is to install non-vented soffit for a few feet on both sides of the bathroom soffit vent.

So now instead of being overly worried about moist warm air entering my attic via the vented soffit, I'm now worried that the 5 feet of venting that I'm choking off will result in decreased ventilation for my attic.

Can those who recommend against venting a bathroom fan to the soffit agree that, at the very least, my method of sealing off the soffit venting around the bathroom soffit vent is an improvement?

By the way, this is [the vent I'm planning to go with](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H5PTSG)

[image]

Comment: really what I'd like to do is use something like this http://www.amazon.com/Speedi-Products-SM-RWVD-Spring-Damper-4-Inch/dp/B0085V07E0/ref=sr_1_7?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1370544286&sr=1-7&keywords=4%22+vent because it has a better damper than the one I listed in my main question (and because a damper makes sense to me to keep the cold air out when the fan isn't in use) but in order to use something like this I would need to create a 90 degree bend (from vertical to horizontal) as a duct/pipe exits the soffit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question, you've got the best compromise if you MUST go through the soffit.

Any reason to not do a roof vent?  [Roof vent,  it has a backdraft damper and a bird screen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQW6LE)

[image]

Comment: The only thing stopping me from going through the roof is that
A.) It's easier to go through the soffit and B.) Going through the roof requires putting a hole in my roof.  Holes in roofs are more likely to leak than pristine shingles.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase this question as:  Which is the lesser of 2 evils:  Preventing water leaks in holes in roofs or preventing moisture intake in the soffit vents near a bathroom fan vent in the soffit?